# Update user location with AWS dynamodb-geo and Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

I am developing an iOS app that displays nearby app users. When a user’s location changes it is send to the server. The app is polling the server once every few minutes to discover currently nearby users. I was using Parse, this worked well. Now I want to replace the Parse backend by AWS services. My idea is to deploy the [dynamodb-geo](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-geo) library in a Lambda function.

I have a DynamoDB table that works with the dynamodb-geo library. It has the *geoHash* as a *hashKey*. For the *rangeKey* I use the *userId*. I can store the location of a user with *putPoint*:

```
GeoPoint geoPoint = new GeoPoint(latitude, longitude);
AttributeValue rangeKeyAttributeValue = new AttributeValue().withS(“someUserId”);
PutPointRequest putPointRequest = new PutPointRequest(geoPoint, rangeKeyAttributeValue);
geoDataManager.putPoint(putPointRequest);
```

To find nearby users I use the *queryRadius* function:

```
GeoPoint currentPoint = new GeoPoint(latitude, longitude);
QueryRadiusRequest request = new QueryRadiusRequest(currentPoint, radius);
return geoDataManager.queryRadius(request).getItem();
```

So far, so good. Now to the problem. An existing user has moved somewhere else and his new location is sent to the server. How do I update his location? I can not use the *putPoint* or *updatePoint* functions. From the javadoc of *updatePoint*:

> Update a point data in Amazon DynamoDB table. You cannot update
>   attributes specified in GeoDataManagerConfiguration: hash key, range
>   key, geohash and geoJson. If you want to update these columns, you
>   need to insert a new record and delete the old record.

I understand why this is the case, it is how DynamoDB works. I can not update the *hashKey*. I have to delete the old item and add the new one. This additional processing raises some doubts about my plan to use dynamodb-geo with Lambda:

I would like to know if my proposed solution using dynamodb-geo with Lambda is a good and scalable approach to implement my use case. I am pretty new to AWS, I am always interested in suggestions for better alternatives.

Comment: How is your solution working out?  I am considering putting dynamodb-geo in a Lambda function as well.

Comment: I abandoned my experiments with the dynamodb-geo library. This library does not work with recent versions of the AWS sdk, and support and maintenance by AWS is poor. I am now investigating a solution using the geo query capabilities of CloudSearch.

Comment: Any news? I'm considering using dynamodb for a location aware app too.

Comment: I decided to use CloudSearch. I have a DynamoDB stream that triggers a lambda function. The lambda uploads documents with location coordinates to CloudSearch. With CloudSearch it is easier to do geo queries.

Comment: Everywhere I've researched on the web explains CloudSearch as the solution to this problem.  However CloudSearch seems costly and still have to deal with the latency somehow.  With the many use cases for this prob I'm surprised AWS doesn't offer a easier solution than feeding documents into CloudSearch.

Comment: @SunnyPatel I agree, I chose CloudSearch as a last resort, after a long search for better alternatives. Costs and latency are serious issues to consider. I was also surprised that there is no better solution for this common use case.