# AWS - Put a GeoPoing in DynamoDB Table and query against it - node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, geolocation, amazon-dynamodb, geospatial

Amazon now has [support for geospatial indexing](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2013/09/05/announcing-amazon-dynamodb-geospatial-indexing/) in DynamoDB but there doesn't seem to be much documentation on how you can do this with the node.js SDK.

I'm trying to understand how to:

1. Put a GeoPoint (geohash) value in an item in a DynamoDB table

And

2. How to query the table for all items within a radius about a location (lat,lng)

I have seen [this article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-geo-library-for-dynamodb/) but am not sure how it would apply in node.js and cannot find any examples

Answer (score 2):

AWS does not offer a library for geospatial indexing for node.js. They only have the java version that you referred to. 
You could use the java library with a lambda function (I tried that), but the library is outdated and not maintained (last commit was 3 years ago)
My [pull request](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-geo/pull/15) with a fix was ignored. 
Even after fixing things myself I ran into issues like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36153366/update-user-location-with-aws-dynamodb-geo-and-lambda).

To answer your questions 1 and 2: AWS wrote [a document series](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/geo-library-for-amazon-dynamodb-part-1-table-structure/) about the way their library calculates geohashes and how it executes queries on DynamoDB. It's too much to summarize here.

The lack of maintenance and support by AWS and the issues I encountered made me conclude that AWS gave up on the idea of geo querying DynamoDB. Besides, I could not find any other developers that have applied this library successfully.

My current solution is based on CloudSearch. I write the items (with their location) into a DynamoDB table. I use a DynamoDB stream that uploads all changes in the table to CloudSearch. CloudSearch has geoquery features out-of-the-box.

Comment: I'm familiar with Cloudsearch but it does not suit my needs because there is a small latency between uploading a document and it becoming available in the index.

Comment: Yes, true. I investigated this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37131035/cloudsearch-performance-with-frequent-updates-of-small-batches My use case is not that time critical.